# Java Annotations - Disabling code

Tags: java, android, logging, annotations, conditional-statements

I want to create some logging functions for Android applications, and i would like to have lines of code that can be disable without having to write `if( traces activated ) trace stuff` every time i want to log something.

Using C macros i could do that by several ways, for example :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#    define TRACE(msg)
#else
#    define TRACE(msg) SomeLogClass::log( msg );
#endif
```

And then just keep the calls to that macro in the code, regardless whether it is active or not :

```
TRACE("blabla")
```

Is there a way to do something similar using Java annotations ?

I could add a boolean flag inside a log class that would or would not log the given message, but the problem with this way is that the parameters given to the log function will always be computed, regardless if the traces are enabled, which would cause some performance loss in frequently called code pieces.

Thank you :)

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a *good* way. I'm also not sure how annotations come into it.

Comment: THere's tools such as antenna that provide macro reprocessing for Java. That's your best bet.  But any solution will require compile time tools as the capability isn't in Java.

Answer (score 0):

At some point you have to check whether logging is enabled or not, there is no workaround sadly. 
One other option might be to use different streams which push your data into nowhere (custom stream with empty methods). The streams would only be defined once at the start of the logging process and thus checking if trace is enabled is not necessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that would still compute parameters even when not needed, which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

i think i found solution for you, for e.g. create your own annotation to work with logging(i would create @Logger :) ) and define pointcuts and join-point(like you use to do in AOP) it should work for you.
Follow this link http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

or you can use android-aspectj : 
http://blog.punegtug.org/2010/11/adding-aspect-to-android.html

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, i'll have a look to that.